# Nextbit robin recognised on fastboot but not adb shell

Tags: adb, fastboot

In the process of rooting my Nextbit Rboin, I unlocked the bootloader, and wiped it so I only have TWRP on it.

I have an LOS zip ready but I dont know how to get it on the device.  I have installed minimal adb and fastboot, and after that adb did not work I also installed 15 seconds adb installer.

```
fastboot -1 0x2c3f devices
```

shows my device but

```
adb push los.zip /sdcard/
```

gives me the error no devices/emulators found.

```
adb shell
```

gives me same error no device found.

```
fastboot update los.zip
```

gives error does not contain android-info.text

How to get the zip on to the robin?  Should I be in fastboot or twep when I run adb?  neither work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `fastboot devices` shows your device, `adb` cannot work (and vice versa).

You need to boot to recovery (TWRP). Then you can push the ZIP via `adb push` and flash it using TWRP's menu (but `fastboot devices` then will show nothing, which is fully normal).

If ADB doesn't work when booted into TWRP, check TWRP's settings whether ADB is disabled. It might also be that, while booted into recovery, your Robin presents a different ID then when in fastboot, so you'd need to configure that (or, in case of Windows, need another reboot for the corresponding driver to update/activate).